# Script to append files

Tags: ruby

I am trying to write a script to do the following:

There are two directories A and B. In directory A, there are files called "today" and "today1". In directory B, there are three files called "today", "today1" and "otherfile".

I want to loop over the files in directory A and append the files that have similar names in directory B to the files in Directory A.

I wrote the method below to handle this but I am not sure if this is on track or if there is a more straightforward way to handle such a case?

Please note I am running the script from directory B.

```
def append_data_to_daily_files
  directory = "B"
  Dir.entries('B').each do |file|
    fileName = file
    next if file == '.' or file == '..'
    File.open(File.join(directory, file), 'a') {|file|
      Dir.entries('.').each do |item|
        next if !(item.match(/fileName/))
        File.open(item, "r")
        file<<item
        item.close
      end
      #file.puts "hello"
      file.close
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: What OS are you using? It's a trivial thing to have Linux or Mac OS append  files: `cat B/file1* >> A/file1`. Embed that in back ticks or `%x`. Remove `*` if you want exact name matches only.

Comment: @theTinMan Can't you open in append mode and write to a file that way rather than going external?

Comment: Hey thanks. I am using Linux and you are right..but I am trying to do this with Ruby as part of an assignment..cheers

Comment: If it's an assignment it would be good to say so in the question. Homework and assignments are supposed to be done by you, figuring it out yourself, not by having others fix it for you.

Comment: Please read through these questions on Meta: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=homework to learn the overall attitude toward homework questions on Stack Overflow, and how you should ask questions tied to homework.

Comment: Tin Man - I didn't ask anyone to change it or "fix it" as you have insinuated. I asked for feedback on my approach. FMc mentioned it could be cleaner and I could use set. Also I have not used any code mentioned below but rather used my own solution posted above.My code is posted below in answer to this problem. If you take a moment to look, you may find that when I asked the question I was 95% of the way there..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, your `append_data_to_daily_files()` method is trying to do too many things -- which makes it difficult to reason about. Break down the logic into very small steps, and write a simple method for each step. Here's a start along that path.

```
require 'set'

def dir_entries(dir)
  Dir.chdir(dir) {
    return Dir.glob('*').to_set
  }
end

def append_file_content(target, source)
  File.open(target, 'a') { |fh|
    fh.write(IO.read(source))
  }
end

def append_common_files(target_dir, source_dir)
  ts = dir_entries(target_dir)
  ss = dir_entries(source_dir)
  common_files = ts.intersection(ss)

  common_files.each do |file_name|
    t = File.join(target_dir, file_name)
    s = File.join(source_dir, file_name)
    append_file_content(t, s)
  end
end

# Run script like this:
#   ruby my_script.rb A B    
append_common_files(*ARGV)
```

By using a `Set`, you can easily figure out the common files. By using `glob` you can avoid the hassle of filtering out the dot-directories. By designing the code to take its directory names from the command line (rather than hard-coding the names in the script), you end up with a potentially re-usable tool.

Comment: Thanks for the post. I see what you mean about being cleaner. I like the use of set

Answer (score 0):

My solution....

```
def append_old_logs_to_daily_files
                directory = "B"
                #For each file in the folder "B"
                Dir.entries('B').each do |file|
                    fileName = file
                    #skip dot directories
                    next if file == '.' or file == '..'
                    #Open each file 
                    File.open(File.join(directory, file), 'a') {|file|
                        #Get each log file from the current directory in turn
                        Dir.entries('.').each do |item|
                            next if item == '.' or item == '..'
                            #that matches the day we are looking for
                            next if !(item.match(fileName))
                            #Read the log file
                            logFilesToBeCopied = File.open(item, "r")
                            contents = logFilesToBeCopied.read

                            file<<contents
                    end
                    file.close
                }
            end
        end
```